# jQuery Snake Carousel Effect

Tags: jquery, carousel

I can't seem to find anything like this, so just asking to see if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I need products to slide around much like a conveyor belt/with a snake effect.

```
View on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLgopodt/2/
```

Crude diagram of functionality required is attached.[image]

Comment: so what have you tried yet? can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: All I have at the moment is some CSS where all elements float left and the jQuery pushes to the start and pops from the end:

[View on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLgopodt/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: well, provide a jsfiddle then. Nobody here is going to write your code for you. (Or well, some might, but that is not the way it works in here...). To get you started: either move the elements absolutely with javascript, or assign classes with transitions with the correct locations

Comment: There's a JSFiddle link supplied in my reply to you...

Comment: and what I'm asking is if there is a jQuery plugin or if anyone has experience doing this before.

Comment: A quick Google search hasn't turned anything up. You might want to look into the possibility of rolling your own plugin for this - jQuery plugins aren't hard to create, and the `animate()` method in jQuery is fairly easy to use.

Comment: it's not that hard, i'll write you something. gimme sec

Comment: Does any update with this ? I have the same problems. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was going to do this with css only, but i couldn't get the :nth-child selector to work correctly.

Anyhow, i updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLgopodt/3/)

- Every column is in a row.
- every `even` row floats the columns to the right
- the javascript prepends columns to the first row and cascades the overflowing columns to the next row
- if there is no next row, it removes the overflowing elements.

`.container .row:nth-child(even) .col
    {
        float: right;
    }`

`var $rows = $('.container .row');
    setInterval(function(){
        var $col = $('<div class="col new">NEW COL</div>');
        $rows.eq(0).prepend($col);
        $col.removeClass('new').addClass('animated bounceIn')
        $rows.each(function(idx, elem){
            var $row = $(elem),
                $cols = $row.children();
            if ($cols.length > 4)
            {
                var $overflow = $cols.filter(':gt(3)'),
                    $nextRow = $rows.eq(idx + 1);
                if ($nextRow.length == 0)
                    $overflow.remove();
                else
                    $nextRow.prepend($overflow);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);`